# Mediaplayer livestream quality issues on Android devices

Tags: google-assistant

We are experiencing severe mediaplayer livestream issues on Android devices for our AoGs with livestream content. However, the behavior is reproducible for AoGs developed by other parties as well.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open an AoG with livestream content (in our German context "Hey Google, rede mit DASDING")
2. AoG opens + Livestream starts playing
3. Livestream quality is experiencing short quality outages.

The livestreams are playing without any quality problems on other Assistant devices like smart displays or smart speakers.

@Team Google: Is this a known problem you are working on?
Is anybody else experiencing these issues?